# How are OS/softwares/updates installed on end-machines in a company

Tags: installation, active-directory, domain-controller, network-monitoring

How are softwares installed on end machines in a company. Going to each machine physically and installing looks very unweildy from administrator point of view. An obvious solution would be to install softwares (and updates) over network. My question on this are:

What protocols,keywords come into picture when administrator installs OS,softwares,updates from his administrator machine to end machine through network. My machine at work is using windows.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet for Windows/Office updates is using WSUS from Microsoft. This will only update Windows and Microsoft products though, but will allow you to distribute it to all your clients over the network.

[WSUS Wiki](http://www.wsuswiki.com/whatiswsus)

Answer (score 0):

There are many options for you to look at.

- Microsoft SMS (right now called Microsoft System Center Manager)
- Altiris NS
- WSUS (for updates - free solution)

You can always utilize GPO software deployment (on demand or on login) which is described in this article: [How to use Group Policy to remotely install software in Windows Server 2003 and in Windows Server 2008](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816102).

Actually there are lots of options, a lot of companies, people offer software to just do that.